# NSAttributedString from HTML - supported tags

Tags: html, ios, nsattributedstring

Which **HTML tags are supported** for conversion from html-text to NSAttributed, using NSAttributed constructor(data: ...) with options:

```
[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
 NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

?

Comment: There is currently no documentation about which tag is supported or not.

Comment: Late answer: You can see some of the unofficial information here https://github.com/johnezang/NSAttributedString-Additions-for-HTML . Some CSS inline styles work too like text-shadow for example.